# cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’

Tags: command-line

I am installing pothosware but the following error occurs:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’
```

I am trying to install through synaptic package manager .

Comment: I'm confused: I didn't think installations via synaptic should require compilation from source code. Anyhow please [edit] your question to include the Ubuntu version (and `g++` version, if you know it): the `c++11` flag is a recent addition to `g++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very short answer, sorry.

To use the `-std=c++11` option you need at least `gcc-4.7`.

---

Check your version with

```
apt-cache policy gcc
```

Comment: Hi A.B I have installed gcc-4.8
Now error is gone.
Thanks for help...